# Prevent CornerOverlapping in linearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

an Imageview is a wrapped in a linearlayout. the linearlayout has a rounded background. I want the imageView not to overlap the rounded corners of the linearlayout. Cardview does something similar but I don't want all corners radius.

Here's my snippet.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_top_stroke"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            android:scaleType="center" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

bottom_sheet_top_stroke

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="0dp"
        android:left="-6dp"
        android:right="-6dp"
        android:bottom="-32dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="40dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

how do I achieve making sure the image is within the defined radius of the parent and not overlap.

Comment: I think you have to make your imageView Rounded. Are you using any third party library for image loading ?

Comment: I'm using Glide to load images. I just need top radius on the image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your Image with roundedCorners.

For Image loading libaries like Glide and picasso there is already lots of transformation available .
You have to use `RoundedCornersTransformation`

```
  Glide.with(this).load(url)
            .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(
                    new RoundedCornersTransformation(this, 10, 10))).into(mImageView);
```

For transformations you can take reference from [glide-transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations)  .